# Javascript - How to disable mousewheel for 1 second

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to disable mousewheel for 1 second. How I can do this?

I have this function:

```
function clickOnMenu(id)
{

    switch(id)
    {
        case 1:
        $('.page').css('display','none');
        $('#first').click();
        rotateImage($('#first'));
        $('#menu div').removeClass('active');
        $('#first').addClass('active');
        break;

        case 2:
        $('.page').css('display','none');
        $('#feature').click();
        rotateImage($('#feature'));
        $('#feature').addClass('active');
        break;

        case 3:
        $('.page').css('display','none');
        $('#download').click();
        rotateImage($('#download'));
        $('#download').addClass('active');
        break;
    }
}
```

These cases run with mousewheel.
I want when each case selected, mousewheel get disable for 1 second.

How I can do this?

Comment: @Boaz I have mousewheel event and i change slides with this, I want to disable it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Attach an event listener to the mousewheel that does nothing. Remove the event listener after 1 second.

```
$('#foo').on('mousewheel', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  return false;
}

setTimeout(function() {
  $('#foo').off('mousewheel');
}, 1000);
```

Comment: this disables mousewheel and not enables again

Comment: the `setTimeout` removes the event handler after 1sec.

Comment: I want remove fast and bind "mousewheel" event again after 1 sececnd

Comment: @chalist: Then just do the reverse of what I am doing in my solution. It's not that hard.